# Apache Redirect Rule to redirect URL present in query parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a URL

www.xyz.com/test/?redTo=www.abc.com||www.google.com&state=abdhs7899928392

I want to redirect this URL to

www.google.com.com/?redTo=www.abc.com||www.google.com&state=abdhs7899928392

("||" is static i want to get www.google.com from redTo query string and pass all the parameters as it is to www.google.com as shown in url above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} redTo=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^/test http://%1
```

Comment: Thanks arco444.It worked.:) But meanwhile requirement got changed :( ,I have updated the question. Please have a look